# Wildfly 16 Elytron Keycloak setup

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, elytron

I am trying to secure ejbs deployed on Wildfly 16 with Elytron and Keycloak to be access from a Java swing front-end. I have checked on the internet and have not found any specific examples on how to do this. Can anyone please help showing the standalone.xml config and wildfly-config. I have install the Keycloak adapter as described in the Keycloak documentation.